# vbtab issue in a do until loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, do-loops

[image: this image show my vbtab problem]

hey guys i am having a problem in my application with the vbtab
can anyone know what is the problem

this is my code:

```
        txtshowpayments.Text = "Student's ID" & vbTab & "Student's Name" & vbTab & "Total Payment" & vbCrLf

    Class217FileReader = New StreamReader("class217.txt")
    PaymentsFileReader = New StreamReader("payments.txt")
    Do Until PaymentsFileReader.EndOfStream
        Do Until Class217FileReader.EndOfStream
            Dim aline As String = Class217FileReader.ReadLine
            Dim aline1 As String = PaymentsFileReader.ReadLine
            Dim fields() As String = aline.Split(","c)
            Dim fields1() As String = aline1.Split(","c)

            Dim StudentId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields1(0))
            Dim studentId1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields(0))
            Dim StudentName As String = fields(1) & " " & fields(2)
            Dim totalpayment As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields1(1)) + Convert.ToInt32(fields1(2)) + Convert.ToInt32(fields1(3))

            If ShouldDisplay(StudentId, studentId1) Then
                txtshowpayments.Text &= StudentId & vbTab & StudentName & vbTab & String.Format("{0:C}", totalpayment) & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
    Loop
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: *You* are supposed to tell us what the problem is.  I am *guessing* you dont like the way the "columns" align in a ListBox?

Comment: @plutonix as you can see in the image the payment column the vbtab is not working in the 2nd and 4th row this is the problem

Comment: A ListBox doesnt have columns; use a DataGridView

Comment: Where is the image ? Can you provide the url.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Format String**:

```
Dim formatString As String = "{0,-12}     {1,-14}     {2}" & vbCrLf

txtshowpayments.Text = String.Format(formatString, "Student's ID", "Student's Name", "Total Payment")
formatString = String.Replace("{2}", "{2:C}")

Class217FileReader = New StreamReader("class217.txt")
PaymentsFileReader = New StreamReader("payments.txt")
Do Until PaymentsFileReader.EndOfStream
    Do Until Class217FileReader.EndOfStream
        Dim aline As String = Class217FileReader.ReadLine
        Dim aline1 As String = PaymentsFileReader.ReadLine
        Dim fields() As String = aline.Split(","c)
        Dim fields1() As String = aline1.Split(","c)

        Dim StudentId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields1(0))
        Dim studentId1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields(0))
        Dim StudentName As String = fields(1) & " " & fields(2)
        Dim totalpayment As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields1(1)) + Convert.ToInt32(fields1(2)) + Convert.ToInt32(fields1(3))

        If ShouldDisplay(StudentId, studentId1) Then
            txtshowpayments.Text &= String.Format(formatString, StudentId, StudentName, totalpayment)
        End If
    Loop
Loop
```

Even better... look into a DataGrid control.